# Debian - g++-mingw-w64 not found

Tags: ubuntu, debian, mingw-w64

I'm trying to compile a Windows cpp program on Linux Debian based and **I have wingw-w64 installed** but on the console it doesn't see it.. How can I solve the problem?

When I try this I get:

```
└─$ g++-mingw-w64                     
g++-mingw-w64: command not found
```

How can I solve this problem?

mingw-w32 works good.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't look like the right file name.

The correct file name will start with the triplet `<arch>-w64-mingw32` where `<arch>` is the processor architecture: `i686` for x86, `x86_64` for x64 (maybe even `aarch64` for Windows on ARM).

*Use:*

- **Windows 32-bit**

  - `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` (C)
  - `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` (C++)
- **Windows 64-bit**

  - `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` (C)
  - `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` (C++)

*Tip:*

To check what platform the generated output (.exe/.dll) runs on use the `file` command. For example:

```bash
echo "int main () { return 0; }" | x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -xc - -o test.exe
file test.exe
```

which returns:

```
test.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

Comment: Is this for x64 right?

Comment: Yes (for Windows 32-bit it is `i686-w64-mingw32-g++`)